# Store a reference to object in a different compilation unit

Tags: c++

Sometimes I need to have access to the same buffer from different compilation units, but due to encapsulation, the direct access is impossible. So, I introduce the method `get` which returns the reference to the buffer.

*Unit1.h*

```
namespace N1 {
    const std::vector<int>& getBuffer();
}
```

*Unit1.cpp*

```
namespace N1 {
    std::vector<int> objects; 
}
```

Since this caused some misunderstanding in comments, let me stress that I can't expose `objects` to other modules directly, I use encapsulation (even insulation) here to make the implementation hidden. Actually, more sophisticated data structure hides behind this `getBuffer` interface.

In the Unit2.cpp I can get the access to the buffer and can work with it. I can call method getBuffer() from any function and use it and I can get buffer address and store in Unit2.cpp to share between all functions of Unit2.cpp.

I have many functions in Unit2 which use this buffer so I’d like to keep a reference to it in Unit2 namespace to avoid requesting it in each function.

The problem is that I can store it in Unit2 namespace only in form of a pointer which allows postponed assignment and not in form of reference, since reference must be initialized with definition and can’t be changed later (except dirty hacks with undefined behavior).

So, I could have in *Unit2.cpp*

```
namespace N2 {
    const std::vector<int>* objects=nullptr; 
}
```

but I can’t have

```
namespace N2 {
    const std::vector<int>& objects; 
}
```

I don’t want to have pointer because of two concerns:

1. When I see a pointer, I always want to check it against nullptr
   before usage, which is excessive here, since this object for sure
   exist as a precondition.
2. The notation ‘.’ is shorter and easier to
   read than ‘->’.

Is it possible in modern C++ to solve this? Some wrappers, etc.? I mostly interested in the syntax rather than in performance here (so, extra indirection could work, although it would be nice to avoid it).

Can this be done with something like `std::ref`, `std::reference_wrapper` or something else without use of compiler-specific tools or additional libraries like boost?

Comment: Since C++17 we have been able to create `inline` variables in headers files so they are easily shareable across TUs.  You could just have in the header file `inline std::vector<int> objects;` and then in unit2 you can just add `using N1::objects;`

Comment: @NathanOliver: Because there's a dedicated implementation file, it's not even needed to make an `inline` variable.  Simply use `extern` to declare the object in its header file (this declaration is presently missing) and define it in one place, which is already being done.  Or does `inline` affect the static initialization order fiasco?

Comment: @NathanOliver, as I stated in my question "due to encapsulation, the direct access is impossible". I don't want other compilation units see the vector directly. Actually, this is a kind of general question, in the real project much more sophisticated structure hides behind the getBuffer and I don't want to expose it. If I got you correctly this will make vector visible and accessible for other modules.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I don't want to expose vector to other clients. They should see the interface only, as I stated in the initial question. I will do my best to stress this in the question, since I was understood in a wrong way.

Comment: I don't know what makes you think that returning a reference and having other clients bind their references to it is not "exposing" the vector.

Comment: @BenVoigt, for example, I could return reference to const buffer, preventing clients from changing the value (updated the questions for this). Anyway, point taken. If so, how about encapsulation? OOP requires to hide implementation details and I hid the vector. Of course, I expose data type, but at least I have a method to access the buffer. In case client code need fast access and can't iterate via class methods, what approach would you suggest for this case?

Comment: Hiding implementation is normally done via PIMPL. But it is pointer-based and depending on ownership model, you need to also hide the deleter. A similar technique can be achieved to hide the element type of a vector(might have dark corners), and it involves hiding the allocator as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW your suggested reference will work just fine, even if the vector hasn't yet completed initialization

```
namespace N2 {
    std::vector<int>& objects = N1::getBuffer(); 
}
```

This is because "before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated, a pointer to or reference to the object may be taken but only used in limited ways..."

See

- https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/basic.life#6
- https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/basic.life#7

Binding a new reference is one of the things that doesn't require the object to be alive yet.

If `getBuffer` can fail if called too early, that's another problem entirely.  In that case you not only want a pointer in `N2`, you want the null checks.

Comment: This is exactly what I tried as a first step and found that this doesn't work (VS 2022). Reference in N2 namespace keeps size = 0 while real object it is intended to refer resized and gets new items. Unfortunately, order of initialization of variables in different translation units (TU) is not defined except some corner cases. So, it is possible that N1::getBuffer will be called before `objects` array is created. I was sure that there is some rule like "if some function in TU is called, its variables should be initialized before the caller", but I can't find this now.

Comment: @DamirTenishev That sounds like a bug in `N1::getBuffer()` not consistently returning the address of the same object.  (References and pointers have different type, but both are implemented as copying around the address)  I suggest printing out the address of the vector in `N1::getBuffer()` and again when you add items to it.

Comment: Ben, thank you for the hint "function not consistently returning the address of the same object", this way of thinking helped me to realize that this should work. I redo my changes to the code and it got working. Unfortunately, I didn't keep previous version which gave different results, so I can't find what was wrong with it. Anyway, now it works just perfect. Thank you again for the hint to way of thinking here.

Comment: @DamirTenishev: Thanks for sharing the outcome.  Glad you have it working.